# HP3525n is printing same job daily from a week ago even though nothing shows in print queue

Tags: printer

How on earth is it possible that my HP3525n printer which is used via wireless, continues to print a job from a week ago and nothing shows up in the print queue, therefore there is not job to cancel. Still, every day about 3 times a day, 10 pages of full color PowerPoint slides print!!!! It's using all my toner. I can't figure it out, I have a ghost in my machine. HELP! Thanks.

Comment: There will be a file in the print spooler folder that hasn't been deleted and Windows keeps trying to process it: `%SystemRoot%\SYSTEM32\SPOOL\PRINTERS`. You need to stop the print spooler service first, before you can delete what's in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a PowerPoint file printing, I assume you are using a laptop/desktop PC to print. I would try these things:

1. Power the printer off
2. With the printer off, reboot the PC
3. After the PC is fully restarted, turn the printer back on.

If that doesn't resolve it:

4. Use the PRINT FILE DIRECTORY on the INFORMATION MENU of the printer (see p. 19 of the [user guide](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/action.process/public/psi/manualsDisplay/?sp4ts.oid=3690646&javax.portlet.action=true&spf_p.tpst=psiContentDisplay&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.prp_psiContentDisplay=wsrp-interactionState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c01528095%257CdocLocale%253Den_US&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) )
5. Print out the CONFIGURATION PAGE to see if that gives you any clues.
6. Uninstall and re-install the printer driver.

Good luck!